# Botkit Slackbot returns error "not_authed" when starting RTM connection

Tags: bots, slack, botkit

I have a slack bot that i wrote in Jan-Mar 2017. However, when I make a new bot with the same code and start it, i get the error "not_authed".

I've debugged the issue and my token is good (ie, if i make a https://slack.com/api/rtm.connect POST call with my token as a body parameter, it works fine and i get a result back). It just seems to be the bot.startRTM method that doesn't seem to be working.

My code is at the bottom:

```
this.controller = botkit.slackbot({
            debug: false,
            stats_optout: true
});
this.bot = this.controller.spawn({
            token: my_bot_access_token_is_here
});

 this.bot.startRTM(function(err, bot, payload) {
        if (err) {
                console.log(err); //I GET THE ERROR "not_authed"
        }
});
```

Any Ideas?